# Iterating all rows and changing a specific value ends up in a disappearing table

Tags: footable

I have following problem: I have a small application running where i have implementes a language switching function. Therefore i need to change the datetime columns in footable for the right date format.
My idea was to iterate through all rows, get the date value, recalculate it in the right format and write it back to the table. But This approach is not working properly, when i try it, you can see the very first row changing, and then the whole table disappears. I have attached some screen shots and the relevant code to explain the problem...

My Code (for iterating the rows and changing the value):

```
var ft = FooTable.get("#spiele_data");
$.each(ft.rows.all, function(i, row){
        v=row.val();
                var m = moment(v.sp_timestamp, 'L LT');
                    v.sp_timestamp=m.format('L LT');
        row.val(v);
    });
```

This is what happens:

Table is loaded and displayes properly
[image: Table is loaded and displayes properly]

After changing the language => see the first line
[image: After changing the language => see the first line]

Immediatley after that the table is gone
[image: Immediatley after that the table is gone]

What am i doing wrong or is there a better possibility to change specific columns in all rows?

Best regards
Christian

+EDIT: One more thing: the `$.each`-loop is iterated completely. I've tested that by writing the index to the console.

Comment: After all, i found a solution for that issue by investigating the JSDocs.
I have to prevent footable from redrawing the table, but force to redraw the row only:

`row.val(v, fale, true)`

solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('table').trigger('footable_redraw');
```

You need to call redraw to see footable again

Comment: Thanks... :)
Unfortunately the Docs are very hard to understand for me...